# How do I disassociate my VS2013 .msi install file from an earlier/forked version of my software?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2013, installation, windows-installer

First, a little background info:

Versions 1.x of my Windows software connect to hardware platform A, and the software is installed using a .msi install script (created with VS2010 and a .vdproj file).

Versions 2.x of my Windows software are similar to versions 1.x, but the v2.x software only connects to hardware platform B (second-generation hardware).  This software is installed using an updated version of the same .vdproj file, build with VS2013.

The above is all well and good, but the problem is that since v2.x of the software controls different hardware than v1.x, users who own both platform A devices and platform B devices will want to have both v1 and v2 of the software installed simultaneously, and the .msi files currently don't allow that.

Specifically, trying to install v2.x while v1.x is installed auto-removes the v1.x software, and trying to install v1.x while v2.x is already installed results in an installation abort, with an error dialog saying "a newer version of the software is already installed".

What I'd like to do is disassociate the 2.x versions of my software entirely from the old v1.x versions, so that (as far as the installer's logic is concerned) they are completely unrelated projects.  They already install to different default install paths (e.g. "\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MySoftware v1" vs "\Program Files (x86)\MyCompany\MySoftware v2"), so that shouldn't be a problem, its just that something in the .vdproj file is still keeping the two projects associated with each other.

I tried changing the "UpgradeCode", "PackageCode", and "ProductCode" GUIDs in the v2.x .vdproj file to something different, but that didn't seem to help; installing v2.x of my software still results in the auto-uninstall/deletion of the v1.x install, and the v1.x installer still aborts if v2.x is installed.

Can someone who is more familiar with the .msi installer's behavior give me a hint on how to make it a little less clever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, I figured out the problem.

Changing the UpgradeCode value is all that is necessary to achieve the behavior I want, but due to the way the software's build process has been set up, changing it in the .vdproj file was insufficient -- there was also a MyProgram.variables.wxi file that was used in the build process, and it contained its own copy of the UpgradeCode value.  Once I changed the UpgradeCode in both places, the disassociation was successful.